# using left join on mutiple tables with conditional statement

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have a problem with MYSQL which can only be solved by using inner join which i am not so good with, i have four tables.

**Table 1: classrooms** 
classroomID, name, .......

**Table 2: teachers**
fname, mname, lname, .......

**Table 3: subjects**
subjectID, name, classroom_id, .....

**table 4 Teachers_subjects**
teacher_id and subject_id

i want a query to get me all class names (classrooms.name) and all its subjects name (subjects.name) 
where subjects.classroom_id = classrooms.classroomID

I also want to get the names of the teachers (teachers.name) where Teachers_subjects.subject_id = subjects.subjectID
and Teachers_subjects.teacher_id= teachers.teacherID.

i am currently using this query :

```
SELECT classrooms.name, subjects.name, 
concat(teachers.fname,' ',teachers.mname,' ',teachers.lname) as Teachers_name  
FROM classrooms, subjects, teachers, teachers_subjects 
WHERE
subjects.classroom_id=classrooms.classroomID 
AND 
teachers_subjects.teacher_id=teachers.teacherID 
AND
teachers_subjects.subject_id=subjects.subjectID
```

I get what i want but i want to get all classes and their corresponding subjects even if its not on the table teachers_subjects. this is to list all classes and its subjects even if the subject is not assigned to any teacher.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like

```
SELECT  classrooms.name, 
    subjects.name, 
    concat(teachers.fname,' ',teachers.mname,' ',teachers.lname) as Teachers_name  
FROM    classrooms INNER JOIN
    subjects ON subjects.classroom_id=classrooms.classroomID  LEFT JOIN 
    teachers_subjects ON teachers_subjects.subject_id=subjects.subjectID LEFT JOIN
    teachers ON teachers_subjects.teacher_id=teachers.teacherID
```

Have a look at this a article ([Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)) for a nice graphical introduction.

Comment: jezzz! i need to go learn this stuff, thanks @astander it works